# How to get squish for iOS working

Tags: ios, qt, testing, squish

I am trying to get squish working for an iOS application. According to froglogic I needed to add in 
`#include &lt;qtbuiltinhook.h&gt;` and also add in `Squish::allowAttaching(11233);` before `app.exec();` along with adding `include(&lt;path&gt;/qtbuiltinhook.pri)` to the projects .pro file.

I have done this and I can see that the port is open on the iOS device when running the app. The problem is that when I run squish I can't attach to the app. I am using attachToApplication("application_that_is_mapped") but get the following error message 
`"Detail RuntimeError: Attaching to AUT 'appName' failed: connection to AUT refused."`

So far the only thing I can tell that may be causing this issue is I was not able to link to the directory containing qtcore.framework when installing squish because I do not have that file. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have you made changes to the linker flags ? Do..

1. Search "Other Linker Flags" in build settings.
2. Expand the Other Linker Flags and select the Squish build configuration.
3. Click the + button in the popup to add the new flags.
4. Enter the flags in order
   `-lstdc++`
   `-lz`
   `-force_load`
   `<squishdir>/lib/arm/libsquishioswrapper.a`
5. Press the Done button.